# why does copy.deepcopy() not work on Bunch(), but storemagic somehow fixes it?

Tags: python, attributeerror, deep-copy, jupyter-lab, bunch

I have a standard Bunch class:

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

This results in an attribute error:

```
a = Bunch(b=1)
a = copy.deepcopy(a)
a.b
```

Which does not make sense to me. The deepcopy() function destroys the functionality of Bunch.

But the really weird part is that adding more complexity fixes it, seemingly by accident:

I am using Jupyter Lab to run things. The following works without error:

```
a = Bunch(b=1)
%store a
%store -r a
a = copy.deepcopy(a)
a.b
```

Why?

Comment: The reason for the original problem is that `deepcopy()` doesn't know that it should keep `__dict__` as a reference to `self`.

Comment: Part of the "magic" of storemagic is that it detects circular references and recreates them. But I'm not sure why that magic persists.

Comment: Shouldn't deepcopy() also detect circular references like this? Isn't that the whole point of the algorithm?

Comment: You may be right. The documentation mentions that it keeps track of which objects it has copied to prevent getting into a recursive loop. Anyway, I think you may need to provide a custom `__deepcopy__` method for your class.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html